# Sniffing packets coming out of "tap interface" when bridge connects to vlan tagged interface

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge

So, I've a tap interface that's created by `kvm` which belongs to a VM being managed via `libvirt`.

The bridge consists of `eth0.123` (here `eth0.123` is a vlan tagged interface) & the `tap device`.

```
[root@compute1 ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
brq732eb7f9-16          8000.002590c6438e       no              eth0.123
                                                        tap81474f06-29
```

When I `ping 8.8.8.8` from the guest:

- I can only sniff `ICMP request` packets on `eth0.123`. There are no `ICMP reply` packets to be seen in the tcpdump.
- On `eth0`, I can sniff both `ICMP request` as well as `ICMP reply` packets.

I'm trying to understand why is that the case. Shouldn't all traffic pass through `eth0.123`?

Comment: It should appear on the tagged interface if your ICMP reply came back tagged. Have you verified your vlan routing?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek How do I verify that? Is it something that's configured on the switch side?

Comment: It'd be on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

No, the bridge registers as the receive handler for the `eth0.123` interface, so the traffic is received into the bridge and not the VLAN virtual interface.

Once you're down into the physical `eth0` interface, this "hook" is gone, so you see the traffic both ways.

**Edit:** Linux Bridging paper provided by asker's further research:

- https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/70789083/linux_bridging_final.pdf

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please share some doc (reference) for further reading? That would be awesome.

Comment: I don't know of any except the kernel source, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted the answer. Can you please add this as a source? https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/70789083/linux_bridging_final.pdf